# PageName segment in Adobe Analytics

Tags: adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

I'm trying to create a segment based on this case:

*"I have an event that is triggered in multriple pages and I only want to see the number of times it has been fired on a specific page."*

I have created a segment where the condition is:

**Page name (URL without domain) -> *contains* -> 'news/potatoe'**

The problem with this is that when I cross this segment against the event, the results are wrong, I get very few hits even though I know, for sure, that the number of hits should be higher.

Adding on, when I breakdown a dimension by "Page name (URL without domain)", I don't get the total ocurrences.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not sure why a segment is needed. If you are capturing the PN in an eVar and setting an event each time the action occurs, you should be able to view the PN dimension and the count of the event by each page.
Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks @MarkStringham for your response. I don't have an eVar with the PN. I'm using the variable by default in Omniture (Page Name URL without domain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pageName variable is kind of an outlier when it comes to event attribution. Instead of giving full credit to the page it fired on, it uses linear allocation, which divides credit equally among all pages seen in the visit. More info on linear allocation can be seen here:

https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/reference/allocate.html

In order to get the data you're looking for, you will want to use an eVar and not pageName. Using a processing rule to copy pageName into an eVar would be the easiest way to accomplish that.

In short, you're pulling the report right with the exception that pageName has weird attribution. If you replaced pageName with an eVar containing pageName data, you'd get the report you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Gigazelle ! I think that It's not possible to cross some events with PageName variable to see where the event is triggered in our site... The only solution, as you proposed, is to create an eVar that collects the page name and sends the new eVar in all the hits, is that right?